# Django: NoReverseMatch in html

Tags: python, django

I am always getting this error in detail.html

`Reverse for 'vote' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s)     tried: ['polls\\/(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)\\/$']`

the detail.html is

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'detail' question.id%} " method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br />
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Vote" />
</form>
```

and my polls.url.py is

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('', views.index, name='index'),

    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),

    path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),

    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

The issue is that I have a similar code `<a href = "{% url 'vote' question.id %}">` in index.html, it will work.

The project directory is here
[directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeaoY.png)

I am so sorry, I found that there is a bug in my views.py

```
def detail(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    choice_set = question.choice_set.all();
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': choice_set})
```

The html is asking for Question but I am passing a choice_set(Question is Choice's foreign key). I am not sure how it led to a NoReverseMatch error. 
Again, thanks for all your help.

Comment: Could you post the contents of your base `urls.py` file?  It looks, (amongst other problems), like you're not including the `polls.url.py` contents.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a redirect in your view perhapse? Because the error is with regards to the `vote` route, and you're using only `detail` route in your template as far as I can see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as per you `url.py` you expect a url `<int:question_id>/vote/` but instead of `int` you are passing an empty string. `... arguments '('',)` so urlresolver does not find any urls that match `<string:question_id>/vote/`.

Not sure, but is possible that you are using this template with an "unsave" `question` object so it does not have `id`

Comment: You just solved the problem, I passed the wrong context argument to the detail.html. THANK YOU~